# FOSS java library for transforming points on a line

Tags: java, timeline

Firstly the library in question is not about graphics its more about converting points along a timeline using a formula into another point upon the same line.

Possibly use cases include animation control, whereby the the point on the timeline represents the current position.

- To play the animation backwards, one simply uses a "transformer" for lack of a better word to calculate the new point from the end rather than the beginning.
- Another possible "transformer" might change the point so progress is no longer linear but rather follows a sine curve.
- Another transformer might double the advancement of the points thus doubling the nimation speed.
- A timer would provide the initial linear input, with other transformers such as the above decorating the exact schemantics of how the animation progresses.